# Issue with custom Authorization in DropWizard

Tags: authentication, authorization, dropwizard

I am trying to add custom authorization in dropwizard but not able to successed.

I have a custom authentication added for dropwizard by binding it to authFactory

```
Authenticator ssoAuthenticator = createSSOAuthenticator(configuration.getSsoGrantClientConfiguration());
environment.jersey().register(AuthFactory.binder(
                    new SSOTokenAuthFactory<SSOGrant>(
                                       ssoAuthenticator,
                                          SYSTEM_PREFIX,
                                         SSOGrant.class))
 );
```

and adding a dynamicfeature for authorization

```
environment.jersey().register(PermissionDynamicFeature.class);
```

Below is the annotation created

```
@Documented
@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER,java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE, java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface PermissionsAllowed {
    String[] value();
}
```

I am checking whether the annotation is present on the method and then registering a filter

```
public class PermissionDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {
@Override
    public void configure(final ResourceInfo resourceInfo, final FeatureContext configuration) {

        final AnnotatedMethod am = new AnnotatedMethod(resourceInfo.getResourceMethod());
        final Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = am.getParameterAnnotations();
            for (Annotation[] annotations : parameterAnnotations) {
                for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
                    if (annotation instanceof PermissionsAllowed) {
                        configuration.register(new RolesAllowedRequestFilter(((PermissionsAllowed)annotation).value()));
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    //@Priority(Priorities.USER) // authorization filter - should go after any authentication filters
    private static class RolesAllowedRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        private final boolean denyAll;
        private final String[] rolesAllowed;

        RolesAllowedRequestFilter() {
            this.denyAll = true;
            this.rolesAllowed = null;
        }

        RolesAllowedRequestFilter(final String[] rolesAllowed) {
            this.denyAll = false;
            this.rolesAllowed = (rolesAllowed != null) ? rolesAllowed : new String[] {};
        }

        @Override
        public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
            if (!denyAll) {
                if (rolesAllowed.length > 0 && !isAuthenticated(requestContext)) {
                    throw new ForbiddenException(LocalizationMessages.USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED());
                }

                for (final String role : rolesAllowed) {
                    if (requestContext.getSecurityContext().isUserInRole(role)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new ForbiddenException(LocalizationMessages.USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED());
        }

        private static boolean isAuthenticated(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
            return requestContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal() != null;
        }
    }
}
```

I am just trying to build my authorization based on the same lines as RolesAllowed filter.

The issue that i am facing is that the Authorization filter is called before the authentication.
What i am missing so that the authentication happens first and the authorization filter is called later?

The same happens when we register RolesAllowedDynamicFeature

```
environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
```

RolesAllowedDynamicFeature is called even before the authentication happens.

Comment: You can control execution of jersey filter by priorities: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e10117

Comment: Tried but still not working. Filter are called first and then the authentication piece.

Comment: Filters are the Authentication piece. Dynamic features are called on constructing your rest api, they are used to register filters as you are correctly doing. So that is normal. Your Filter does NOT have an order set. You can have a look at the Priorities class, jersey even defines special priorities for Authentication and Authorization. If you can update your question with a mini example that I can just run, I am happy to have a closer look.

Comment: The main problem is that the Filter for permission checking added via DynamicFeature is called before the Authentication registered by AuthFactory is called. I added the Priority @Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION) and tested still it is being called before the Authentication. Even if i dont add the custom permission checking filter and just add the `environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);` in the application then also the RolesAllowed filter is called before the actual authentication happens and it fails. Will try to send across the example.

Comment: So, looking a bit closer into AuthFactory, I believe that is your problem. The auth factory does not provide a priority/order. Could you try implementing the AuthFactory as a separate Filter with a priority and see if that works? Alternatively, can you add @Priority(Integer.MAX_INT) to your other filters? That should put them behind USER priorities and make them execute last. It would point towards a bug in AuthFactory.

Comment: tried adding @Priority(Integer.MAX_INT) to the Permission Filter but it is still getting called before the authentcation. The AuthFactory implementation is custom implementation, don't have source code for the same right now.

Answer (score 0):

so based on your answers I wrote up a test and I believe I can tell you what's the issue here.

The Authfactory you are using to provide Authentication tokens is not a request Filter. based on the documentation of jersey, this is the execution order of a request:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9976

The issue is the following:

ALL request filter will always be executed before your binding is executed. At the time of the request, jersey doesn't even know if it needs to bind anything to your method at all. Why should it create anything, a filter might reject the request before it gets to execution.

So in short, annotating your resource method with @Auth simply adds an injection binder to your jersey environment. You can read about custom injection here:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html

This obviously works correctly and is quite handy, however not what you want. 
What you want is to reject a request before it passed through any filter. For this you MUST write a request filter. Annotate it with the correct priority and everything should be working fine.

You could have a think about extracting your auth logic into a common class (Which you already did) and then register the same class with a RequestFilter and your Authenticator, therefore keeping the Auth provider, while still having request filtering based on Authentication.

```
run(...) {

   myAuthStuff = create()
   jersey.register(MyAuthRequstFilter(myAuthStuff));
   jersey.register(MyAuthInjectionBinder(myAuthStuff));

}
```

Add a cache and you won't have to worry about calling the same thing twice.

I believe dropwizard did not intend this to work with filters. It appears their intention was to inject the auth context into a resource method and do authentication etc in there. Not my preferred solution, but it could work.

So to sum stuff up:

What you want to do is not supported by dropwizard out of the box. The solution is to extend their solution into a request filter.

Hope that helps,

Artur

Comment: So, We need to add the authenticaiton piece in two places, one is using the AuthFactory which i am currently doing and the other is to add authenticator to the filter. So the authentication is done first using the filter and then the PermissionChecked filter will be called and then the @Auth will call the authentication using the AuthFactory. Is my understanding correct ? U mentioned about the cache can you please elaborate as to what do you mean by it ?

Comment: Yes you are correct, you will have to add that twice. The cache is because the filter and the AuthFactory will essentially do the same thing, right? So by caching the first call to authenticate, you don't have to do it again (auth can be expensive). (look at guava loading cache for example). You could also think about skipping the AuthFactory and do all the logic in your filter instead. Do you really need the Auth object in the method? If so you could always store it somewhere from the filter (threadLocal for example) and re-use it that way.

Comment: Thanks for quick response and help. Appreciate it. So in filter i create instance of SSOTokenAuthFactory and call its provide method and it should work fine right ?

Comment: This depends on your implementation. If your factory requires an injection, you might need to do it manually. it might be better to extract that logic and call it directly with the current request. Looking at BasicAuthFactory it will have to have the request injected. If you want to use that code, you will have to worry about thread-safety as well.  Basically, I would extract the logic in Provide, have a thread-safe helper class that has a method provide(httpRequest) and then call that method with the request in both my factory and my filter.