# How to Optionally Protect a Resource with Custom Dropwizard Filter

Tags: java, authentication, jersey, authorization, dropwizard

I'm using Dropwizard 0.9.2 and I want to create a resource that requires no authentication for GET and requires basic authentication for POST.

I have tried

```
@Path("/protectedPing")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class ProtectedPing {

@GET
public String everybody() {

    return "pingpong";
}

@PermitAll
@POST
public String authenticated(){
    return "secret pingpong";
}
```

with

```
CachingAuthenticator<BasicCredentials, User> ca = new CachingAuthenticator<>(environment.metrics(), ldapAuthenticator, cbSpec);
AdminAuthorizer authorizer = new AdminAuthorizer();
BasicCredentialAuthFilter<User> bcaf = new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>().setAuthenticator(ca).setRealm("test-oauth").setAuthorizer(authorizer).buildAuthFilter();
environment.jersey().register(bcaf);
environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));
environment.jersey().register(new ProtectedPing());
```

This seems to result in all requests to "/protectedPing" requiring basic auth.

In Dropwizard 0.9.2 the documentation says to create a custom filter if I have a resource that is optionally protected.  I'm assuming I need to do that, but I don't know where to start, or if that I what I actually need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is more of a jersey problem than a dropwizard problem. You can have a look here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html

Essentially what you want is:

1. Create an annotation that indicates that you want to test for authentication (e.g. @AuthenticatePost)
2. Create the resource and annotate the correct method with @AuthenticatePost
3. Create your authentication filter (probably kind of like what you did above).
4. In the dynamic feature, test for the annotation to be present on the passed in resource. This will hold true for post, false for get. Then register the AuthenticationFilter directly on the resource method instead of globally on the resource.

This would be a semi-complete example of how I would solve this:

```
public class MyDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        if(resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(AuthenticateMe.class) != null ) {
            context.register(MyAuthFilter.class);
        }
    }

    public class MyAuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
            // do authentication here
        }

    }

    public @interface AuthenticateMe {

    }

    @Path("myPath")
    public class MyResource {

        @GET
        public String get() {
            return "get-method";
        }

        @POST
        @AuthenticateMe
        public String post() {
            return "post-method";
        }
    }
}
```

Note, the DynamicFeature checks that the Authenticate Annotation is present, before registering the authentication with the feature context.

I hope that helps,

let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this, thank you!  I figured it was more of a Jersey question, but approaching it from a Dropwizard direction made figuring out the Jersey words difficult

Comment: I believe Jersey has a similar approach, where you use the Auth to bind a user into the resource method. If the user can't be created, it will not be able to execute the method. This however does not consider all pre-matching filters, which will run regardless. If you are interested, here's some info from a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304323/issue-with-custom-authorization-in-dropwizard/34334097#34334097