# how to set header authentication in dropwizard

Tags: api, authentication, dropwizard

I've built a small api.
I Would like to implement header authentication for my api.
When user want to access my api he will send his apikey along with the api url. If the apikey was in my database then he will be given access, if not he can't access the api.

Comment: I answered a similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304323/issue-with-custom-authorization-in-dropwizard/34334097#34334097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to authenticate a single method
then you can look for the header directly in the method itself. something like

```
    @GET
    public Response processRequest(
            @HeaderParam("X-APIKEY")              
            @DefaultValue("INVALID_OR_GUEST_KEY") String apikey , ...)
```

if you want to establish this for -all- (or most) of your methods, then you are better off with a filter. Take a look at http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html#jersey-filters and  http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html#servlet-filters .
You can implement your key lookup logic in there

(PS you may want also to consider caching them, but that's another story).

Comment: Thanks Daniele it works fine. How can we built cache for the API to store the apikeys, because every time hitting the database is not efficient.

Comment: Hi, look at guava caching for this maybe: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained Loading cache seems like exactly what you would like to have.

Comment: You could use something like memcached (memcached.org)or (especially if your application needs to scalable) hazelcast (hazelcast.org) . they are both pretty darn good!