# How to declare custom field/paramether annotation similar to Auth in Dropwizard

Tags: java, annotations, dropwizard

I have secured resources with `@Auth` annotation on User entity.

But I want to control the flow of data, so that requests without header will be also valid (by default, Dropwizard Auth returns 401 Unauthorized).

I think that the best for it would be my custom annotation, which will be applied to User parameter, and, if from `SecurityContext` userPrincipal is null, then I can return some default User or just pass the null further.

How to implement such an annotation? Or maybe You have other suggestions?

EDIT
I think that I found the code that may suit my needs :

```
User user = (User) context.getUserPrincipal();
```

But how can I make paramether annotation from it, so that this would be executed to every annotated object?

Comment: The problem is not with the `@Auth` annotation feature specifically. The component that gets the value for the annotation just gets it from the `SecurityContext` that is set in a filter. Maybe what you want to write your own filter, and not register Dropwizard's

Comment: Take a look at the source code for the [`BasicCredentialAuthFilter`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v0.9.2/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/basic/BasicCredentialAuthFilter.java). Just modify it as you need it. Then register yours instead of DW's. The code I linked to is for 9.2 You should probably change the tag to whatever version you are using, as the implementation has changed in different versions

Comment: I believe this may be a similar issue to this one I have answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304323/issue-with-custom-authorization-in-dropwizard/34334097#34334097

Comment: No, I have search a code which may suit my needs : `User user = (User) context.getUserPrincipal()` . But i dont know how to make annotation from it that will do this operation for every paramether annotated with it.

Comment: Your code to get the user will happen _after_ the auth filter. So if you use the same Basic auth filter from Dropwizard, you will still fail when there is no header. Your code to try to get the user will never be hit. That's why I said, just write a new filter. And just use the same functionality provided by the `@Auth` annotation